# Server wide auth for all Virtualhosts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.4

I am trying to apply Apache auth for the Virtualhosts in my Linux server. The issue here is the Virtualhosts running under separate user inside the server and the document root is also different from each other. If I go to implement the auth, I need to edit each Virtualhost file inside the *sites-enabled* dir. This is a time-consuming task as there 300+ sites enabled in the server.

Is there any option/tool to implement this? I mean a server-wide single auth.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have 300+ sites and you aren't using automation?!

Comment: @MichaelHampton  these are simple wordpress and staic page websites just using for internal demo purpose only :)

Comment: For cases like this it is always handy to have an "IncludeOptional" directive poiting to a specific file for all the virtualhosts you define, but I'm with Michael here...